# Apply Changes in Additional Drivers stuck for nVidia Drivers (16.10, ASUS GTX1060 3G)

Tags: system-installation, 16.10, nvidia-geforce, additional-drivers

I've done a clean install of 16.10. The default, nouveau, video driver has abysmal resolution on my GTX1060. I brought up the Additional Drivers app and selected the "Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 367.57 from nvidia-367 (proprietary, tested) and pressed the button to apply changes.

The process got to, perhaps, 80% complete and appears to have just stuck there. I've let it sit for 24 hours in case it was just a very slow update.

Screenshot of the Additional Drivers app window attached.

[image: Additional Drivers Window]

Comment: Update: I closed the app and restarted, now it shows a message to the effect that the system must be rebooted for changes to take effect.

I do so and got the infamous login-loop. System starts, presents the login screen (even though I've set it to log in automatically). Entering my password just gets me back to the login screen.

I entered in recovery mode, purged the nvidia drivers, and tried this time adding the graphics drivers ppa, and manually (via apt-get) the nvidia-375 driver (latest). Same results.

Lots of posts about this but I've not found a definitive solution.